# Clicking on NSURL in a UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, ios9, nsurl

I have a `UITextView` that spans 100.0 points across my `UIView`.

In the `UITextView`, I have links that get captured with the following function:

```
- (BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
```

This works great to capture certain characters but I have one problem: if the link is the last characters in the text view, then the tap will get pressed all the way across that line.

So if I have the text view with the following text where @test is the link:

```
// The entire remainder of the line will be the link (all the white space after @test)
Hello @test
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Means you want the blank space to open the link?

Comment: Will it highlight the remaining if the `@test` link trails with a whitespace? Is it happen on iOS 9 only?

Comment: I DO NOT want anything after @test to be linkable but by default it is

Comment: Try with adding `[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\u2063" attributes:nil]` at the end of your `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: cool that does work. i think it helps with the attributes:nil. I can see why they made the bounds as it's harder to click now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it only highlights the link... Am I missing something?

[image]

Update:

Here's a really hacky solution via dummy URL's:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSMutableAttributedString* attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
    [attributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vim iuvaret blandit intellegebat ut. Solet diceret interpretaris eos cu, magna dicat explicari mei ex, cibo adversarium eu pro. Ei odio saepe eloquentiam cum, nisl case nec ut. Harum habemus definiebas et vix, est cu aeque sonet, in his salutatus repudiare deterruisset. Quo duis autem intellegat an, regione propriae et vis."]];

    NSAttributedString* dummyUrl = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" " attributes:@{ NSLinkAttributeName : @"http://dummy.com" }];
    NSAttributedString* url = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com" attributes:@{ NSLinkAttributeName : @"http://stackoverflow.com" }];
    [attributedString appendAttributedString:dummyUrl];
    [attributedString appendAttributedString:url];
    [attributedString appendAttributedString:dummyUrl];
    self.textView.attributedText = attributedString;
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange {
    return ![URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"http://dummy.com"];
}
```

Basically you force the `UITextView` to recognise the tap before and after the stackoverflow link as the dummy link. Since it's just a space it's invisible, however unfortunately if you tap and hold before/after the stackoverflow link you'll see the space highlighted with gray, despite `shouldInteractWithURL` returning `NO`. 
Unfortunately it seems you cannot circumvent this behaviour unless you implement your own `UITextField` from scratch...

Comment: yes but what if you tap/click 20 points to the right of .com that is highlighted?

Comment: I see what you mean. But it's not just the area after the link, it's also the area to the left, above and below the link. Basically the tap area of the link extends beyond the visible boundary (if no other link is nearby) to make tapping on the link easier. I'd be surprise if you could customise this behaviour.

Comment: so essentially leave it alone and don't touch (i.e. they won't let you)

Comment: just noticed you work at prezi? cool software we used to present and get a job

Comment: @chris either you have to accept this behaviour, or try the hack I've updated my answer with. Honestly, I'd recommend the former. Also, keep on using prezi! :)

Comment: Accept the behavior is probably best. And accept the bounty. Are you in SF?

Comment: Nope, I'm in Hungary. Maybe I'll visit SF soon, we'll see.

Comment: Ah I see, crunchbase has you in the budapest office. Thx for your help. Off to bed as its late in SF.

Comment: You are adding an extra space. This behavior may create a new line (for example in case of UITextView adapting its size to its content (especially the height), while in case of adding a invisible space, it should do the trick. Plus, I'd avoid setting at all an attribute for the space, it's just useless.

Answer (score 2):

As Tamás Zahola suggested in previous answer, you can fix this issue by adding "dummy" URLs before and after real URL. But, instead using whitespace in dummy link, use zero width space unicode character:

```
NSAttributedString* dummyUrl = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\u200B" attributes:@{ NSLinkAttributeName : @"http://dummy.com" }];
[attributedString appendAttributedString:dummyUrl];
[attributedString appendAttributedString:url];
[attributedString appendAttributedString:dummyUrl];
```

Answer (score 0):

[image] You simply need to set some properties after linking that textView to code like textview delegate, editable and dataDetectorTypes

Below i have added the content i have used

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson3.html Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. http://stackoverflow.com Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda http://stackoverflow.com

### for objective-c

```
textView.delegate=self:
textView.editable = NO;  
textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;


- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange {
   return true;
```

}

### for Swift

```
textView1.delegate=self
textView1.editable = false
textView1.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.Link

func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```