# Clicking on a link attribute in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, ios9, nsurl, nsattributedstring

I have a UITextView defined as:

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40);
```

I then have an attributedText like so:

```
textView.attributedText = @"Testing #tag";
```

When this is on the screen, the attributed text only takes up half (or so) the width of the text view.  But since I made the #tag a clickable link and used the function below, all the white space after #tag is clickable.

```
- (BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
```

How do I stop white space from being clickable?

Comment: does anyone have ideas?

Comment: Why the duplicate `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34825841/clicking-on-nsurl-in-a-uitextview`?

Comment: older post but then i made a bounty to increase interest, but still yet to have an answer

Comment: you might want to make duplicate link clickable too